# Responsive snake game

Tags: javascript, jquery, snake-game

#### Snake

Snake first appeared in the 1970s. Since then it has become a video game classic that is pre-installed on many systems.
The rules are simple:
Food (often an apple) appears randomly on the grid.  When the snake "eats" the food, the snake grows a little.
The player loses if the snake hits the edge of the grid or the snake itself.

For more information, please have a look at the article on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_(video_game_genre)).

#### My implementation

I've used pure JavaScript and a bit of JQuery in this project. The code also works on mobile devices.

#### The code

```javascript
let WIDTH = 400;
let HEIGHT = 400;

let RES = 20;

let snake = [];

let direction;
let tempDirection;

let isRunning;
let interval;

let appleX;
let appleY;
let scoreCount = 0;
let highscore = 0;

let snakeLength;
let speed;
let isSet;

// Resize canvas when screen too small - needed for responsiveness
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  /*
   * Normal width of canvas = 400, so resize only needed when
   * screen-width < 400
   */
  if (window.innerWidth < 400) {
    WIDTH = document.getElementById('chooseDifficulty').clientWidth;
    HEIGHT = WIDTH;
    document.getElementById('canvas').height = HEIGHT;
    document.getElementById('canvas').width = WIDTH;
    RES = WIDTH / 20;
  }
});

/*
 * difficulty choice
 */
document.getElementById('easy').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById('chooseDifficulty').style.display = 'none';
  snakeLength = 5;
  isSet = true;
  speed = 120;
  initialize();
});

document.getElementById('medium').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById('chooseDifficulty').style.display = 'none';
  snakeLength = 7;
  isSet = true;
  speed = 100;
  initialize();
});

document.getElementById('hard').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById('chooseDifficulty').style.display = 'none';
  snakeLength = 9;
  isSet = true;
  speed = 80;
  initialize();
});

/*
 * control via arrow keys
 */
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  /*
   * case user didn't choose difficulty yet
   */
  if (!isSet) {
    return;
  }

  /*
   * Needed, because otherwise the arrow-up and arrow-down key would also lead
   * to a scroll up and down
   */
  e.preventDefault();

  /*
   * Start / Stop game with space
   */
  if (e.code === 'Space') {
    if (!isRunning) {
      start();
    } else {
      stop();
    }
  }

  /*
   * User shouldn't be able to change direction
   * when game hasn't started yet
   */
  if (!isRunning) {
    return;
  }

  /*
   * Direction change needs to be saved in a temporary variable,
   * because otherwise, the user would be able to cheat.
   * Let's say the current direction is UP. Then the user could
   * quickly press the left-arrow and then the down-arrow
   * -> direction would change from UP to DOWN
   *
   * That's why the direction change is saved in a temporary variable
   * and the main direction variable is only updated once per 'generation',
   * but only if the rules allow the direction change (up to down not possible!)
   */
  if (e.key === 'ArrowUp' && direction !== 'DOWN') {
    tempDirection = 'UP';
  } else if (e.key === 'ArrowDown' && direction !== 'UP') {
    tempDirection = 'DOWN';
  } else if (e.key === 'ArrowLeft' && direction !== 'RIGHT') {
    tempDirection = 'LEFT';
  } else if (e.key === 'ArrowRight' && direction !== 'LEFT') {
    tempDirection = 'RIGHT';
  }
});

/*
 * Button to start / stop the game in mobile view
 */
document.getElementById('startStop').addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (!isSet) {
    return;
  }

  if (!isRunning) {
    start();
    document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
    updateElement('startStop', 'Stop');
  } else {
    stop();
    document.body.style.overflow = 'scroll';
    updateElement('startStop', 'Start');
  }
});

/*
 * Functionality to change the direction of the snake with swipe-movements
 * added with swiped-events.js
 * https://github.com/john-doherty/swiped-events
 */
document.getElementById('canvas').addEventListener('swiped-left', function() {
  if (!isSet || !isRunning) {
    return;
  }

  if (direction !== 'RIGHT') {
    tempDirection = 'LEFT';
  }
});


document.getElementById('canvas').addEventListener('swiped-right', function() {
  if (!isSet || !isRunning) {
    return;
  }

  if (direction !== 'LEFT') {
    tempDirection = 'RIGHT';
  }
});

document.getElementById('canvas').addEventListener('swiped-up', function() {
  if (!isSet || !isRunning) {
    return;
  }

  if (direction !== 'DOWN') {
    tempDirection = 'UP';
  }
});

document.getElementById('canvas').addEventListener('swiped-down', function() {
  if (!isSet || !isRunning) {
    return;
  }

  if (direction !== 'UP') {
    tempDirection = 'DOWN';
  }
});

function initialize() {
  // Did user reach new highscore?
  if (scoreCount > highscore) {
    highscore = scoreCount;
  }

  // Update highscore
  updateElement('highscore', highscore);

  // Reset
  snake = [];
  direction = 'RIGHT';
  tempDirection = '';
  isRunning = false;
  appleX = -1;
  appleY = -1;
  scoreCount = 0;

  // display score = 0;
  updateElement('score', scoreCount);

  // Get center of canvas
  const x = Math.floor((WIDTH / RES) / 2);
  const y = Math.floor((HEIGHT / RES) / 2);

  // Set head of snake to center and then go left for tail
  for (let i = x; i > x - snakeLength; i--) {
    snake.push({x: i, y: y});
  }
  draw();

  // Show text to tell user to start game with pressing space
  const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.font = '30px open-sans';
  ctx.fillStyle = '00410B';
  ctx.textAlign = 'center';
  if (WIDTH === 400) {
    ctx.fillText('Press space to play', canvas.width / 2, 100);
  } else {
    ctx.fillText('Press start to play', canvas.width / 2, 100);
  }
}

function start() {
  // Update canvas every 'speed' milliseconds
  interval = setInterval(function() {
    draw();
    applyRules();
  }, (speed));

  isRunning = true;
}

function stop() {
  // Stop updating the canvas
  clearInterval(interval);
  isRunning = false;
}

function youLost() {
  // Reset
  document.body.style.overflow = 'scroll';
  snakeLength = -1;
  isSet = false;
  speed = -1;
  updateElement('chooseDifficultyText', 'Game over.\nChoose difficulty:');
  updateElement('startStop', 'Start');
  stop();

  // Show 'choose difficulty'-menu again
  document.getElementById('chooseDifficulty').style.display = 'inline-block';
}

function draw() {
  const cols = WIDTH / RES;
  const rows = HEIGHT / RES;

  // Draw
  for (let i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
      const x = i * RES;
      const y = j * RES;
      drawCell('white', 'LightGray', 1, x, y, RES, RES);
    }
  }

  // Draw snake
  for (let i = 0; i < snake.length; i++) {
    // Head of snake
    if (i !== 0) {
      drawCell('#2B823A', 'LightGray', 1, snake[i].x * RES,
          snake[i].y * RES, RES, RES);
    } else {
      drawCell('#00410B', 'LightGray', 1, snake[i].x * RES,
          snake[i].y * RES, RES, RES);
    }
  }

  // Draw apple
  if (appleX !== -1 && appleY !== -1) {
    const img = new Image();
    img.src = 'apple.svg';
    const ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
    ctx.drawImage(img, appleX * RES, appleY * RES, RES, RES);
  }
}

function applyRules() {
  // Check if head of snake is outside of canvas -> game lost
  if (snake[0].x > WIDTH / RES - 1 || snake[0].x < 0 ||
      snake[0].y > HEIGHT / RES - 1 || snake[0].y < 0) {
    youLost();
  }

  // Check if head touches other part of the snake -> game lost
  for (let i = 1; i < snake.length; i++) {
    if (snake[0].x === snake[i].x && snake[0].y === snake[i].y) {
      youLost();
    }
  }

  // Place new apple in canvas
  if (appleX === -1 && appleY === -1) {
    getApple();
  }

  // users direction-change takes place here
  if (tempDirection !== '') {
    if (tempDirection === 'UP' && direction !== 'DOWN') {
      direction = tempDirection;
    } else if (tempDirection === 'DOWN' && direction !== 'UP') {
      direction = tempDirection;
    } else if (tempDirection === 'LEFT' && direction !== 'RIGHT') {
      direction = tempDirection;
    } else if (tempDirection === 'RIGHT' && direction !== 'LEFT') {
      direction = tempDirection;
    }
  }

  // Get position of head
  const headX = snake[0].x;
  const headY = snake[0].y;

  // Add new 'head to snake' to let snake move
  if (direction === 'UP') {
    snake.unshift({x: headX, y: headY - 1});
  } else if (direction === 'DOWN') {
    snake.unshift({x: headX, y: headY + 1});
  } else if (direction === 'LEFT') {
    snake.unshift({x: headX - 1, y: headY});
  } else {
    snake.unshift({x: headX + 1, y: headY});
  }

  /*
   * If snake didn't eat an apple in this iteration, the last element of
   * the snake has to be removed so that snake has same length after
   * moving on cell
   */
  if (snake[0].x !== appleX || snake[0].y !== appleY) {
    snake.pop();
  } else {
    /*
     * Case that the snake did eat an apple in this iteration. The last
     * element of the snake doesn't gets removed because that way,
     * the snake grows. Position of the apple gets resetted.
     */
    appleX = -1;
    appleY = -1;
    scoreCount++;
    // Update score

    updateElement('score', scoreCount);
  }
}


/*
 * ===================
 * HELPER
 * ===================
 */
function drawCell(fillStyle, strokeStyle, lineWidth, x, y, width, height) {
  const ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
  ctx.fillStyle = fillStyle;
  ctx.strokeStyle = strokeStyle;
  ctx.lineWidth = lineWidth;
  ctx.beginPath();

  // Draw border of color strokeStyle
  ctx.rect(x, y, width, height);

  // Fill cell with color fillStyle
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.stroke();
}

function getApple() {
  let isInSnake = false;
  while (!isInSnake) {
    isInSnake = true;
    // Get random position for apple
    appleX = Math.floor(Math.random() * (WIDTH / RES - 1)) + 1;
    appleY = Math.floor(Math.random() * (HEIGHT / RES - 1)) + 1;

    // Iterate over every element of the snake
    for (let i = 0; i < snake.length; i++) {
      /*
       * If the newly created position for the apple is occupied by the snake,
       * another position for the apple has to be found.
       */
      if (snake[i].x === appleX && snake[i].y === appleY) {
        isInSnake = false;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}

function updateElement(elemId, content) {
  /*
   * isNaN returns true if variable isn't a number
   * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN
   */
  if (!isNaN(content)) {
    /*
     * creates a string of length 3, e.g. if content = 15,
     * then result will be 015
     */
    content = content.toString().padStart(3, '0');
  }
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#' + elemId).text(content);
  });
}
```

#### Question

All suggestions are welcome.

Comment: I tried your demo and it seems to work fine. The only niggle I have is that it seems somewhat slow to respond to my inputs on the keyboard. I didn't try touch. A probable cause is too much redrawing. After each interval you should only draw what changes. I like your comments, that helps to understand the code.

Comment: I think that when I swap `applyRules();` and `draw();` around, in the interval loop, so that `applyRules();` comes before `draw();`, that it is slightly better. This makes sense: After each interval the code first reacts to the keyboard, or touch, and then does a complete redraw, instead of the other way around.

Comment: I would not do `document.getElementById` in event handlers, try to save them in variables there is no need to check it each time the event happen. Also I don't know if you know but every element with id define global variable with same name, but using those globals, would probably make the code less readable. Also I don't see the reason to call `document.getElementById('canvas')` multiple times.

Comment: I also have question at the end you use jQuery ready, then why you don't use jQuery for other part of the code? The code would be shorter if you use jQuery, otherwise I would remove it, using it only for document ready is overkill.